# Try Catch not working inside function / functions

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

2 functions one calls the other.

The CATCH blocks in the function Export-LoggedOnUser are not being triggered when I leave either the $path parameter or the $ComputerName parameter NULL. The Export-LoggedOnUser function is calling the first function "Get-LoggedOnUser". It too will not trigger the catch block if I leave the $ComputerName Parameter null. I have written these in various ways and they both work as desired except the TRY/CATCH structures do not perform in either function.

The Typical error is some always some variation of a 'ParameterBindingValidationException' which is to be expected except that it is not being handled in the CATCH. I'm flummoxed. Gotta be something simple.

```
    function Get-LoggedOnUser{
     [CmdletBinding()]
          [Alias()]
          Param
          (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName 
           )
Try{
  ForEach($computer in $ComputerName){
     $output = @{
     'ComputerName' = $computer;     }#OutputHashTable
     $output.UserName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop).Username    
     [PSCustomObject]$output
     }
  }
Catch{
    Write-host 'You must enter a valid computername'
     }
  }

#New Function
function Export-LoggedOnUser{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
   Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
         )
    try{
     $loggedonuser = Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction stop 
     
       }
    catch{
         Write-Host "You need to provide a Computername"
        }
    Try{
     $loggedonuser | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation -ErrorAction Stop
     }
    Catch{
     Write-Host 'You must enter a valid path'
     } 
 }
```

Comment: parameter validation happens during binding, which is before the body of the function (where your try/catch lives) is executed

Comment: To touch on what @MikeShepard is saying, you would have to "*look*" at the parameters and see what is null. You can do so using `$PSBoundParameters`.

Comment: Actually, my point is that if you're getting parameter validation exceptions there wouldn't be any opportunity for $PSboundParameters, because you wouldn't ever get into the body of the function.  Similarly for try/catch in the body of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian,

If you want to test the $Computername parameter and provide an error message I'd drop the parameter validation and do the following:

```
Function Test {

Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [String[]] $ComputerName
)

If ($Null -ne $ComputerName) {

  ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        $GCIMArgs = @{Class        = 'Win32_ComputerSystem'
                      ComputerName = "$computer"
                      ErrorAction  =  'Stop'}

    Try   { $UserName = (Get-CIMInstance @GCIMArgs ).Username }
    Catch { "Error: $Computer is an invalid computer name!"   }

<#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
  | Place your code her to place $username in your PSObject!  |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------+
#>

  } #End ForEach

} #End If ($Null -ne $ComputerName)

Else { "You must supply a valid array of computer names..." }

} #End Function Test

#--------------------  Main Program ---------------------

Test @("DellXPS8920","Dellxps8700","JanetsLaptop")
```

If run as shown above you get this output:

```
Error: JanetsLaptop is an invalid computer name!
```

Which is correct for my lan since that laptop was not turned on.

If you just call TEST with out the array you get this:

```
You must supply a valid array of computer names...
```

Comment: Thanks RetiredGeek. I was able to take your example and with a couple of mods, bend it to my will.